# How to skip uac for electron application with perMachine set to true

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, nsis

i want to skip uac prompt while installing the electron application. i have set perMachine:true in my package.json

Thanks.

i have tried changing installer.nsi file changing requestexecutionlevel from admin to user but still it is prompting for uac

Comment: 1. Open the installer.nsi file in a text editor.
2. Find the line that starts with "RequestExecutionLevel".
3. Change the value of this line to "user".
4. Save the file and close the text editor.
5. Rerun the installer.

Comment: i tried changing installer.nsi with RequestExecutionLevel to user but still it is prompting for UAC

Answer (score 0):

Per-Machine and UAC elevation go hand in hand. Per-Machine means you are installing for all users on a machine and this means you will write to Program Files and HKLM and this requires UAC elevation.

If you don't want UAC elevation then you must set perMachine:false (install per-user into the users %LocalAppdata%\Programs and HKCU)...

Comment: i tried changing installer.nsi files too but uac is still getting prompted. so, is it not possible to skip uac untill we change permachine to false ??

Comment: I don't know anything about Electron but I assume it overrides whatever you put in the .nsi. The solution is to change perMachine to false...

Comment: Hi Anders,
can we add any group policy including all the users that have this application in order to skip UAC.

Comment: I don't think so. If you have control over these systems I suppose you can arrange for the installer to be executed by a service or scheduled tasks or things like that.